# Increase height of slide using react-slick in vertical mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

I am building a timepicker/timeroller using react-slick (unsual, I know).

I am struggling to increase height of slides, so that I can have more space to work with on mask area (place where grey hours and minutes titles are)

Here is what I got so far (dont mind terrible react code, focus on CSS):

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-forked-ozdol

Here is what am I aiming for:

[image]

Seems like the problem is with setting the height of each slide, but I am unable to get it right, looks like Slick always calculates the height automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this style snippet should do the trick.

```
.slick-slide div {
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Enjoy!